# fetch values from different table having same fields

Tags: mysqli

i have a web page that calculates total mark of 3 months after 3 months. But the marks are in different fields. So I need to fetch values from different tables having the same field. I used the following query. Can anyone correct this query, because with this query it loads whole months value rather than 3-month value. But when I fetch from a single table it loads correctly

```
select empid,name,total1 from ((select *,sum(total)as total1 
from formresult5 GROUP by empid) UNION (SELECT *,sum(total)as total1 
FROM formresult4 GROUP by empid) UNION (SELECT *,sum(total)as total1 
FROM formresult3 GROUP by empid) UNION (SELECT *,sum(total)as total1 
FROM formresult2 GROUP by empid) UNION (select *,sum(total)as total1 
FROM formresult GROUP by empid)) result 
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') 
    AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
    AND branch='$branch' ORDER by total1 desc
```

I have 6 tables to store evaluation result of 6 type categorized employees. there empid(employee id), name, total are same field for all table and I need to fetch those same columns and the sum(total) means the sum of previous three month total mark
now I had edited my code to

```
select empid,name,total1 from ((select *,sum(total)as total1 from formresult6 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) GROUP by empid) 
UNION 
(select *,sum(total)as total1 from formresult5 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) GROUP by empid) 
UNION 
(SELECT *,sum(total)as total1 FROM formresult4 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) GROUP by empid)
 UNION 
(SELECT *,sum(total)as total1 FROM formresult3 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) GROUP by empid) 
UNION 
(SELECT *,sum(total)as total1 FROM formresult2 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) GROUP by empid) 
UNION 
(select *,sum(total)as total1 from formresult WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) GROUP by empid)) result 
where branch='$branch' 
ORDER by total1 desc
```

In  this code my page worked correctly, when executing this code in phpmyadmin it shows "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." I worried this warning affect my code execution in my web page
Can any one help me

Comment: that alert just means you don't have a unique column - it does not affect your code execution, only trying to edit and such in phpMyAdmin - i.e., just as the text says (you should look that up if it concerns you).  So, you have changed the code and now you say "my page worked correctly" - does that mean you don't need more help?

Comment: With that code it does not affect code execution, then there is no problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how you use/define $branch - if you leave it like that then unless you have "$branch" in your data, you won't see anything.

Comment: Actually, that is not a problem, because I used a single branch name instead of that variable. My problem is when I used this code all values are returning rather than 3-month value. But when I fetch from a single table it returns correct 3-month value.

Comment: You should then change your question to just what you are saying....  Show "this sql from a single table returns the correct 3-month value" and then the one that doesn't.  Don't presume anyone can magically understand your data and layout, etc. - from some a 'complex' query it makes it difficult on others to help you, so 'spell it out' (one way I was taught is "say it like you are explaining it to a 3rd grader" - when you do that, you often fix it yourself, or at least others can easily help.

Comment: I am really sorry. for the complexity I made.

Comment: no problem, you are learning.  Just 'help others help you'.  If you can also give some sample data from each table that should help (yes, it gets to be a lot, but how can someone that never saw your data understand?).  My guess is you are overwriting all the 'different' data because of all the repeated use of 'total1', but not sure until more info is given.  You might try changing the 'total1' to match the table (i.e., 'total5' for 'formresult5', etc. - then look at the results.  I'm just not seeing how you are bringing it together.....

Comment: I have 6 tables to store evaluation result of 6 type categorized employees. there empid(employee id), name, total are same field for all table and I need to fetch those same columns and the sum(total) means the sum of previous three month total mark